# Поочередное открытие процесса с его последующим закрытием с другого процесса

Tags: python, python-3.x, процесс

Есть два python скрипта, который запускают друг друга по очереди каждые 10 секунд. Проблема в том, что процесс предыдущего python процесса не закрывается.Так показывает Process Hacker. Логику решил построить так : Что python проверяет на наличии python.exe в процессах и PID этих процессов, и если PID новосозданного процесса **не равен** другим PID, то этот новосозданный процесс закрывает процессы связанные с python.

Если **коротко** : One.py открывает Two.py, при этом Two.py при запуске закрывает процесс с One.py.

***One.py***

```
import time
import os
import psutil

from subprocess import check_output
def get_pid(name):
    return check_output(["pidof",name])

PID = os.getpid() # узнаём PID данного процесса.
PROCNAME = "python.exe"

print(f"I am ONE! Process id is {PID}")
time.sleep(10)
os.system("python two.py")
time.sleep(5)
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    # check whether the process name matches
    if proc.name() == PROCNAME and get_pid(PROCNAME) != PID:
        proc.terminate()
time.sleep(1)
```

**Two.py**

```
import time
import os
import psutil

from subprocess import check_output
def get_pid(name):
    return check_output(["pidof",name])

PID = os.getpid()
PROCNAME = "python.exe"

print(f"I am TWO! Process id is {PID}")
time.sleep(10)
os.system("python one.py")
time.sleep(5)
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    # check whether the process name matches
    if proc.name() == PROCNAME and get_pid(PROCNAME) != PID:
        proc.terminate()
time.sleep(1)
```

Что я делаю не так?

Решил пойти иным путём:

**One.py**

```
import time
import os
import psutil
import sys


time.sleep(10)
if len(sys.argv) > 0:
    for arg in sys.argv:
        p = psutil.Process(arg)
        p.terminate()
else:
    PID = os.getpid()
    print(f"I am ONE! Process id is {str(PID)}")
    os.system(f"python two.py {str(PID)}")
```

**Two.py**

```
import time
import os
import psutil
import sys


time.sleep(10)
if len(sys.argv) > 0:
    for arg in sys.argv:
        p = psutil.Process(arg)
        p.terminate()
else:
    PID = os.getpid()
    print(f"I am TWO! Process id is {str(PID)}")
    os.system(f"python one.py {str(PID)}")
```

Получая данную ошибку:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что как только запускаете скрипт, его pid появляется в списках процессов? Поэтому проверять, равен ли pid текущего скрипта какому-нибудь pid с python.exe бессмысленно.

Comment: @strawdog, да вы абсолютно правы. Только вот без `get_pid(PROCNAME) != PID` другой процесс с питоном не завершается.

Comment: Посмотрите запуск процессов через  `subprocess.Popen`, там можно не ждать окончания запущенного процесса, т.е. вызывающий завершается, а  `os.system` ждет завершения.  Кстати, программу лучше вызывать не по имени `python`, а использовать `sys.executable`, а то вдруг на компе не не один питон...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решил!**

**One.py**

```
import time
import os
import psutil
import sys


time.sleep(2)
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    # for arg in sys.argv:
    p = psutil.Process(int(sys.argv[1]))
    p.terminate()
    PID = os.getpid()
    print(f"I am ONE! Process id is {PID}")
    os.system("python two.py " + str(PID))
else:
    PID = os.getpid()
    print(f"I am ONE! Process id is {PID}")
    os.system("python two.py " + str(PID))
```

**Two.py**

```
import time
import os
import psutil
import sys


time.sleep(2)
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    # for arg in sys.argv:
    p = psutil.Process(int(sys.argv[1]))
    p.terminate()
    PID = os.getpid()
    print(f"I am TWO! Process id is {PID}")
    os.system("python one.py " + str(PID))
else:
    PID = os.getpid()
    print(f"I am TWO! Process id is {PID}")
    os.system("python one.py " + str(PID))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Есть два python скрипта, которые запускают друг друга по очереди

Всё это можно реализовать гораздо проще и без использования `psutil`, `os.system` и `pidof`.

```
import sys, os, time
name = f'{__file__} {os.getpid()}, {(counter := int(sys.argv[1]))}'
with open('log', 'ta', encoding='utf-8') as log:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print(f"I am {name}", file=log)
    if counter:
        import subprocess
        next_file_path = 'two.py' # или 'one.py' в случае файла 'two.py'
        subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, next_file_path, str(counter-1)])
        print(f"exit {name}", file=log)
    else:
        print(f"stopped {name}", file=log)
```

Поскольку все новосозданные процессы, а также процесс командной оболочки используют одни и те же ресурсы вывода (`sys.stdout`), гораздо правильнее отслеживать ход программы через специальный файл (`log`). Вызов `time.sleep(0.1)` необходим для того, чтобы логи не перекрывали друг друга (хотя это всё равно не является 100% гарантией). Для запуска программы указываем в окне консоли:

```
python one.py X
```

где `X` это число рекурсивных вызовов. Ниже пример вывода программы при `X`=4:

```
I am one.py 12328, 4
exit one.py 12328, 4
I am two.py 224, 3
exit two.py 224, 3
I am one.py 15208, 2
exit one.py 15208, 2
I am two.py 1800, 1
exit two.py 1800, 1
I am one.py 10656, 0
stopped one.py 10656, 0
```

Для запуска скриптом самого себя достаточно заменить строку `next_file_path = 'two.py'` на `next_file_path = 'one.py'`. Пример для `python one.py 1`:

```
I am one.py 13804, 1
exit one.py 13804, 1
I am one.py 3120, 0
stopped one.py 3120, 0
```

Здесь каждая строка `I am ...` указывает на создание нового процесса, строка `exit ...` - на его закрытие. Заметьте, что процессы никто не закрывает - они закрываются сами. Однако если вам по какой-то причине (надеюсь по причине любознательности, не стоит так делать в реальном коде) нужно закрывать процесс-родитель именно из процесса-ребёнка, вы бы могли это сделать так:

```
import sys, os, time
name = f'{__file__} {os.getpid()}, {(counter := int(sys.argv[1]))}'
with open('log', 'ta', encoding='utf-8') as log:
    print(f"I am {name}", file=log)
    try:
        parent_pid = int(sys.argv[2])
    except IndexError:
        pass
    else:
        import signal
        os.kill(parent_pid, signal.SIGTERM)
        print(f"exit {parent_pid} from {name}", file=log)
    if counter:
        log.flush() # обязательно опустошаем буфер, ведь нас принудительно закроют 
        import subprocess
        next_file_path = 'one.py'
        subprocess.run([sys.executable, next_file_path, str(counter-1), str(os.getpid())])
        print(f"this is unreachable {name}", file=log)
    else:
        print(f"stopped {name}", file=log)
```

Пример для `python one.py 3`:

```
I am one.py 14652, 3
I am one.py 10976, 2
exit 14652 from one.py 10976, 2
I am one.py 9084, 1
exit 10976 from one.py 9084, 1
I am one.py 11548, 0
exit 9084 from one.py 11548, 0
stopped one.py 11548, 0
```

По сути мы просто убиваем процесс который нам передали в аргументах. Однако такое взаимодействие можно организовать через файлы, сокеты и т.п. Процесс не обязательно убивать - его можно попросить самоубиться. Посмотрите также иные способы запуска и остановки процессов:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.spawnl
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fork
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html